# Python/ploty - How to reverse axis direction in a Parallel Coordinates plot?

Tags: python, plotly, reverse, axis, parallel-coordinates

I'm trying to make a Parallel Coordinates plot with plotly.graph_objs
Here is my code.

```
'''
import plotly.graph_objs as go
layout = go.Layout( autosize=False, width=800, height=600)
fig = go.Figure(data = 
    go.Parcoords(
        dimensions = list([
            dict(range = [1,9],
            label = 'col1', values = df.col1),
            dict(range = [1,9],
            label = 'col2', values = df.col2),
            dict(range = [1,9],
            label = 'col3', values = df.col3)
        ])
    ), layout = layout
)
fig.show()
'''
```

This graph works, but I need to reversed y-axis.
Here 3 are what i tried

1. fig.update_layout(yaxis=dict(autorange="reversed"))
2. fig.update_yaxes(autorange='reversed')
3. fig['layout']['yaxis']['autorange'] = 'reversed'
   But none of these works.
   How would I have a reversed graph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly you could just reverse the `range` parameter:

```
import plotly.graph_objs as go
layout = go.Layout( autosize=False, width=800, height=600)
fig = go.Figure(data = 
    go.Parcoords(
        # Reversed ranges.
        dimensions = list([
            dict(range = [9, 1],
            label = 'col1', values = df.col1),
            dict(range = [9, 1],
            label = 'col2', values = df.col2),
            dict(range = [9, 1],
            label = 'col3', values = df.col3)
        ])
    ), layout = layout
)
fig.show()
'''
```

Before (fake data):

[image]
After:

[image]

Comment: WHAT A GENIUS YOU ARE Thank you so much. :)

Comment: Nice. Exactly what I was looking for.